# How to read space separated string in one line using Scanner class?

Tags: java, string, split

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int t = sc.nextInt();
 String s = sc.nextLine();
 String[] arr = s.split(" ");  
 //not able to split the string by whitespace" ".
```

Comment: Does this help: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine` here reads the rest of the line first [according to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), so you need another call to `nextLine`.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // added
String s = sc.nextLine();
String[] arr = s.split(" ");
```